# append text to Message Body - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an `MFMailComposeViewController` to make a Contact Us Channel in my App. I want to add a technical details in the email How I can achieve this?

```
[mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[[mailer navigationBar]setTintColor:DEFAULT_COLOR];
[mailer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
[self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

The `setMessageBody`method Can't be used because the message will be written by the user

What is the solution ??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _technical details_ ?

Comment: @oxxy after setting body user still have the option to edit that detail

Comment: @bhargavg like the app version the iOS Version the iPhone type etc...

Comment: @InderKumarRathore so you suggest to write the technical details at first and let the user write his message after that ?

Comment: You need to alter the message in mailer view after user typed the message and attach the required details after user finishes composing message and just before the message is transfered. Can u post the code in the mailer view?

Comment: Just use an attachment.... [mailer addAttachmentData:filename:mimeType] something like this, i don't remember exact syntax